# i7-5820k Overheats in BIOS

Tags: bios, overheating, intel-core-i7

I have read several posts in which folks have overheating issues after some time, with certain applications, or due to moving/damaging the machine.  I just built mine (first time) and the machine overheats while in BIOS.  The reason I am surprised is that I am using the same [passive heatsink](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835114128) and CPU identified in a Thinkmate configuration that I acquired while shopping around.

When I let it go unmolested, the temperature quickly gets into the 70s before I shut it off.  Actively cooling it with an external fan brings the temp down to reasonable levels, which makes me think and active cooler would solve the problem.  Nevertheless, is this behavior unusual?

Comment: Sounds like the heatsink isn't going to do the job.  No; Its not usual your better of using the stock fan

Comment: cooler's only good to 150w, that CPU can pull 350 under load. Agree with @Ramhound it would be better off with a stock cooler.

Comment: Interesting.  So it sounds like if I had purchased off the shelf from Thinkmate, I would have been hosed?  I just assumed they would package something that worked.

Comment: I would never use a "passive" heatsink on a modern i series processor. Get one with a fan and be sure you mount it properly with a high quality heat sink compound.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the heatsink, it has its place, but on a cpu with 140W TDP you absolutely need airflow across it. Surely the Thinkmate configuration you're talking about has some kind of wind "tunnel" where the case fan actually pulls air across and through the heatsink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the helpful comments.  I ended up picking up a Corsair H110 liquid cooler to replace my Dynasim heatsink, and my temp has stabilized around 35 C.